# CCAVENUE with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I follow this step from http://aravin.net/how-to-integration-ccavenue-payment-gateway-into-your-website-using-asp-net-with-screenshot/.

I am doing this with asp.net c#(mvc).

Still I am getting following error:

Error Code: 10001 Invalid Request – Encrypted request invalid/not present.

Don’t worry… It happens to the best of us.

Along with that I want to store “Error Code” which is "order_status" in response code of ccavenue in database
whether it is success or failure with its code number.
how can I do that.
Thank You.

Comment: did you try to print out stack trace?

Comment: what do you mean @HienNguyen.. I didnt get it..